# Nginx reverse proxy exposes my real ip to client

Tags: docker, nginx, cloudflare

I'm using cloudflare to hide my server ip.When i look up for ip with 3rd party tools it shows cloudflare ip.But i can see my real server ip in Request Header > Remote Addres section.
How can i change it to cloudflare ip or any other solution ?

I use nginx reverse proxy on serverside.

[image: screenshot]

I tried to change destination of the proxy but it doesnt matter even i remove it , request still shows the real ip of the server.

Comment: sounds like your browser is not getting the same IP from DNS as your 3rd party tools.  Possibly your browser sees a cached DNS Response.  you don't provide any supporting details so we can't really help you debug this one.

Comment: X-Real-IP and X-Forwarded-For are common HTTP headers to add. Are you saying you don't want them?